# Color code certain div tag created by for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop

So I created a div with class using a for loop. Is the div I created in an array like myDiv[1]?
How can I manipulate the divs I created so I can color code each div that is odd or every 5th div? Or if I want to color the div if a value is over 10.

```
<?php 

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++) { ?>
            <div class='myDiv'>
            <b> Hello </b>
            </div>
       <?php }


?>
```

Comment: Give each div a different name for complete control, or use `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` to style odd and even ones, or `nth-child(5n)` to style every fifth div? The div you created is not in an array, unless you put it in one.

Comment: ntn-child works but I want to color-code a div based on a specific condition, if the div contains values over 500 or something

Comment: Maybe I should add that in the question I'm asking sorry.

Comment: Then the answer below would allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Similarly check for any condition and apply class eg: even, odd and add styles for that. You can also try a pure CSS method using `:nth-child(n)`, but check for your target browser compatibility

```
<?php 

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++) { ?>
            <div class='myDiv <?php if($i % 5 == 0) { echo('color-red'); } ?>'>
            <b> Hello </b>
            </div>
       <?php }


?>
```

**CSS**

```
.class-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Another example as per OP comment

> if the div contains values over 500 or something

This should work

```
 <div class='myDiv <?php if($i > 500) { echo('color-red'); } ?>'>
```

Comment: That doesn't style every fifth div, it only styles _the_ fifth div.

Comment: @droopsnoot Thanks for pointing out, hopefully it should work now.

Comment: Yes that works, can I also " <div class='myDiv <?php if($money > 10) { echo('color-red'); } ?>'>" if I have like a $money variable inside the div?

Comment: @EricLin You can add any condition using any variable, the point is that the div should have the class. Browser should see the html as `<div class="class1 class2 class3">....</div>`. Remember to add spaces between classes.